# JavaScript Binary Tree w/ Breadth First Search

Tags: javascript, c++, angularjs, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Transitioning from C++ into web development and am curious about BST and data structures in general in AngularJS.

I would like to create a BST with a breadth-first search option. In C++, I'd create a node with a left and right pointer. Then use a queue to enqueue the root node, see if matches the desired value and if it does not, push the child elements and dequeue the root.

I am not really sure where to begin with this in JavaScript AngularJS, as there are no structs or pointers. When performing an $http.get() in AngularJS, I would like to store the data in a BST and search for items with BFS.

Can anyone suggest a starting place? Would using pure JavaScript to create a custom data structure be preferable?

**Edit**: changed "node" to "struct;" edited question header "AngularJS" to "JavaScript," as I now understand underlying data structures would be built in the base language and not the framework.

Comment: In almost all web contexts, you will never need to work with BSTs directly. For almost anything you do on web, there's a framework or library. My advice would be to research first, unless of course you're doing it for educational purposes.

Comment: Predominantly for educational purposes and coming up to speed with AngularJS. I know a hash map can be created and am curious about additional data structures. Perhaps if a BST is not available I can create one as a reusable component; might not be practical but it's fun.

Comment: Of course. *AngularJS* itself is a web framework, not a language. If you want to implement Data Structures, you will be doing those in *JavaScript*. Learning Angular will entail learning how to use the framework to build *controllers, factories, services* etc. Happy coding!

Comment: There are no nodes in C++ either ...

Comment: Thank you, this helped clarify the concept for me; it is the underlying language of the framework that is used to create data structures, not the framework itself. It seems like JS is what I was looking for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31513/linkedlist-and-binary-search-tree-in-javascript ; http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/09/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a mvc framework... has nothing to do with data structures.

So yeah you'll have to do it with pure js.

There are some libs that might make it easier see: https://lodash.com/docs and http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: This makes sense now; as Spring is an MVC framework for Java and AngularJS is a framework for JavaScript, using the framework to create a data structure would not make sense. I'll look into pure JS and play around with creating a BST there. Thanks!